# Terraform Remote StateFile for multiple instances of same configuration and Terraform design

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+, terraform-remote-state

I have a requirement to create a set of a same number of instances for each of our customers. Let us assume my customers Walmart, Apple, and eBay. Each customer has same number of Instances but configuration(subnet, number of disk and disk sizes, OS Images) changes. So I created a variable file for each customer and used it to launch the instances. Until now everything is working as expected. I am able to launch instances for each customer with their own configuration and also able to modify instances as required.

Now, I am trying to move statefile from my local to remote. In `backend.tf` how do I take the `key` as dynamic? Upon investigating `backed.tf` can't accept any interpolations (variables) as it is loaded much before than the core of Terraform can be initialized.

1. How do I solve this problem? I tried the below approach but I have to run `init` every time I switch customers.

`terraform init --backend-config "key=apple.tfstate"`

2. Is there any fundamental issue with the approach I followed to create instances using a separate variable file?
3. Do I need to use a single state file for all customers? if so I have 40+ customers, having all of the customers in a single file might be risky/bulky/slow right?

I am **not** using Terraform Enterprise or Terraform Cloud. Please let me know how to proceed. Thanks!

I use the below command to apply terraform changes

```
terraform apply -var-file=customers/apple.tfvars -state=statefile/apple.tfstate
terraform apply -var-file=customers/walmart.tfvars -state=statefile/walmart.tfstate
```

Folder structure

```
  ├── main.tf
  └── variables.tf
  ├── gcp_compute_disk
  │   ├── gcp_compute_disk.tf
  │   └── variables.tf
  ├── gcp_instance
  │   ├── gcp_instance.tf
  │   └── variables.tf
  ├── customers
  │   ├── apple.tfvars
  │   ├── ebay.tfvars
  │   ├── walmart.tfvars
  ├── statefile
  │   ├── apple.tfstate
  │   ├── ebay.tfstate
  │   ├── walmart.tfstate
```

Comment: Maybe [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) would be better. You could make have a different workspace for each custom.

Comment: Especially because the abstraction between customers' environment can be described in variables; otherwise, you could also have separate root module configs for each customer.

Comment: @Marcin So I have to create 40 Workspaces, one for each customer ? And each will have its own backend.tf file? 40 s3 buckets and 40 dynamo DB table?

Comment: @Eva I think you don't need 40 buckets and tables. You can try with some dummy 2 or 3 customers, and check how it works. If you are satisfied with how workspaces fit into your requirnments, then you can think how to do it for real. Or as other comment said, maybe keep them fully separated in different root folders.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks will try and let you know. I was not clear with the root folder idea. would it be possible to share the structure?